# Mongo Query on a JSON object

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an element in a mongoDB collection that looks like below. The value `"abcdefgh"` changes for each row. How do I query to get the row that has the value `"abcdefgh"` within the object that is stored under the `_id` field?

```
"_id": {
    "abcdefgh": {
        "w": true,
        "r": true
    }
```

Comment: I think your terminology is inaccurate here; "abcdefgh" is not a _value_, it is a _field_.

Comment: @VinceBowdren, I am not much sure about the terminology. However, "abcdefgh" varies for each record in the collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists) operator, i.e. try something like this

```
db.yourCollection.find({"_id.abcdefgh": { "$exists": true } })
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. It returns the error "We encountered an error while parsing your JSON. Please check your syntax (e.g. ensure you are using double quotes around both your field names and values) and try again."

Comment: With what did you try it? I tested it in mongo shell and it worked; did you quote "_id.abcdefgh"?

Comment: Maybe you also have to quote $exists for your used driver - I updated the answer. Please try again

Comment: Wonderful. Yes, it worked now. Thanks a lot. I accepted the answer